# GetCaretPos() works improperly?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I want to use the GetCaretPos() Win32 API to get the position of the caret of a textbox, even when it's invisble.  It seems to work OK if the textbox has only one line, but the more lines it has, the more different the Y-coordinate of the caret is (as reported by GetCaretPos().  The Y-coordinate of the caret reported by GetCaretPos() is always greater than the actual Y-coordinate of the caret.

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private extern static int GetCaretPos(out Point p);
[DllImport("user32")]
private extern static int SetCaretPos(int x, int y);
[DllImport("user32")]
private extern static bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("user32")]
private extern static int CreateCaret(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int width, int height);
//Suppose I have a TextBox with a few lines already input.
//And I'll make it invisible to hide the real caret, create a new caret and set its position to see how the difference between them is.

private void TestCaret(){
   textBox1.Visible = false;//textBox1 is the only Control on the Form and has been focused.
   CreateCaret(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 2, 20);
   Point p;
   GetCaretPos(out p);//Retrieve Location of the real caret (calculated in textBox1's coordinates)
   SetCaretPos(p.X + textBox1.Left, p.Y + textBox1.Top);
   ShowCaret(Handle);
}
```

As I said, anywhere the `textBox1` is on the form, when it's invisible, calling the method above will show a faked caret at the exact position of the real (hidden) caret.  It works OK when textBox1 has only 1 line, but not when it has multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

The text box does not have a caret when it's not focused (thus also when it's not visible). Specifically, only one control ("window") per thread can have a caret at any moment. This means that the text box has to store the caret position in some other way while it's not focused or invisible, and create a new caret at the stored position when it's focused again.

This leaves you with two options:

1. get and store the caret position before the text box loses focus (use the Leave event or create a class that inherits from the TextBox class and override the LostFocus method).
2. use the SelectionStart (+SelectionLength) properties of the TextBox and the GetPositionFromCharIndex method to find the position at which the caret would be created when the text box gets focused again.